# Import in eclipse project cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I just copied my entire eclipse and workspace onto my computer. I suddenly get an error in a project that i didnt get before.

This import cannot be resolved
import jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global;

[image: Build Properties]

[image: Build Properties]

I normally added the JDK as an installed JRE for eclipse.

Im using Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2 for Java developers

Comment: Are you *deliberately* importing an internal package? That sounds like a bad idea to me.

Comment: Its actually a library written by someone else. But my project depends in this one and i did some modifications to it. https://code.google.com/p/rcaller/source/browse/RCaller/src/main/java/examples/SampleGui.java thats the source code. The import didnt make a problem before i had to newly set up my pc

Comment: look farther down you libraries view for any jars with a yellow mark on them indicating they are not there.  you may have copied the project but not the actual jar.

Comment: btw, what your showing there is not enough to really help would help to have the actual error messages in problems view.

Comment: You should add that package into your lib folder.